# New to <%# - weird error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a TemplateField to add an extra "calculated" column to a gridview that is bound to a table in a database. I'm getting this weird error and I have no clue how to begin to debug it. I might be doing something wrong/non-doable with the `<%#` syntax and if so please let me know what. I don't fully understand it.

Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Math.Round(decimal.Parse((((int.Parse(Eval("Num1").ToString())) * 36) / (235 * int.Parse(Eval("Num2").ToString()))).ToString()), 0); %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Error:
CS1525: Invalid expression term ','

There is a comma...but its for the second argument of Math.Round. Or am I doing something that is not do-able in this way? Also, the Math.Round line doesn't indicate any errors in the code-behind (my parenthesis should be good).

Comment: remove the semicolon ; and try

Comment: It looked alright for me.  It does seem like a fairly confusing line of text.  If Num1 and Num2 are being computed, perhaps it would be better to compute this value as well.  That way, you could just say '<%# Eval("ComputedValue") %>'

Comment: @Narnian Num1 and Num2 are columns in a table in the database the Gridview is bound to.

Comment: @novacara Could you set up a property with the computed value?  What are you using, C#, VB?  The class that represents that table could just have an a extra property, it seems.

Comment: @Narnian I am using C# indicated in the tag above. The table is in a SQL Server database. How do you set up a property?

Comment: @novacara On whatever class C# is using, you can just add a property that does the computation.  So, wherever your Num1 and Num2 are definfed, define another Num3 and define it as computed.  Alternatively, it is possible to add a computed column on a SQL table, but I've never done that.  As another alternative, you can reference a method on your code behind that does the computation.  <%# ComputeValue((int)Eval("Num1"), (int)Eval("Num2")); %>

Comment: @Narnian I think your answer helps me the most. Thanks for your help! If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @novacara Ok... I kind of summarized it.  Glad that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looked alright for me. However, it does seem like a fairly confusing line of text. If Num1 and Num2 are columns in your database, then you can just add a property on the class that represents the table.

So, next to where Num1 and Num2 are defined, define another property--not representing a column in the database, but a computation of values in the database.

This removes the computation from one specific page, so if you have to use it again somewhere, you can just reference the property.

Alternatively, you could reference a method on your code behind...

```
<%# GetComputedValue((int)Eval("Num1"), (int)Eval("Num2")) %>

protected string GetComputedValue(int num1, int num2)
```

I like the property idea better, though, since it is reusable.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have another column that needs to be a complicated if statement so the code behind method will work better for everything. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

In an databind expression, you're limited to  a single statement. Drop the ";". I'll trust the statement itself is well-formed.

Comment: For future reference to anyone I got ';' expected because I needed a ToString() at the end since its going into a Label. Not the most helpful errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the ability to do the rounding etc just create a public function in your code behind that is called Round and call that from the data binding expression(s).  That way you don't have any issues with a comma as well as having all your logic in one place so it is easier to maintain consistency later on.

Comment: Great idea! Is there a way to access the data-bound variables from a method in code-behind however? You see I am "Eval"-ing Num1 and Num2 above?